# declaring array size shadows a local variable

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I am in  CS50 week 2 arrays bulbs problem
I have a function to turn ASCII value into 8 bit binary then store value in array the problem is without declaring the size of the array it gives error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized and if I declare the size of the array it gives error: declaration shadows local variable I don't know what to do obviously new to coding any and all help is appreciated here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char* message = get_string("message:");
int i=0;
int array[7]; //this is what gives declaration shadows local variable also have tried int array[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
          //without this line I get the variable-sized object may not be initialized down bellow
while (message[i] != '\0')
   {
      int j= message[i]; // this converts char to ASCII
      for ( h=7;h>=0;h--)  
          {
               if (j % 2 == 1)
                 {
                    int array[h]=1;// if I don't shadow this when declaring size above I get variable-sized 
                                     // object may not be initialized

                     j=(j/2);   // I don't actually know if this will result rounding down the .5 since its an 
                                //int but that's really the least of my worries right now
                  }          
                  else
                  {
                    int array[h]=0;   //the point of the code is to print each of the chars in the message to an 8 digit binary
                    j=(j/2);
                  }
                    for ( int y=0;y < 8; y++)
                    {
                      printf("%i",array[y]);  //I understand that I am shadowing the array but if i change  the name of the array to array1 then its a new array and would get error variable sized object may not be initialized
                    }
                      printf("\n");
                    i++;
           }
     }
  printf("\n");
}
```

so I'm sure there are plenty of problems with this code and that it could be better optimized but all I really care about is how I can declare the size of the array without shadowing local variable. Also I had to rewrite all this code line by line copying what I have in visual studio so there could be an syntax error somewhere here that's not in my actual code this is unfinished even with the array error fixed I will still need to print it as light emoji and not ones and zeros.

Comment: You have two variables with the same name. Compiler warns you about that.

Comment: Did you mean `array[h]=1` instead of `int array[h]={1}` ?

Comment: Please edit the question adding an explanation of what the purpose of the code is. Right now, that purpose is unclear.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Looks like the code is supposed to print message in binary form.

Comment: You have several local declarations of `array`:  One at the op-level of `main`, and two inside inside the if-else chain in your `for` loop.  The latter two shadow the first, meaning their presence masks the first and makes it impossible to reference it.  This is almost always a bug.  The fix is equally obvious:  Change some of the names.  E.g. rename one of them to `array2` or some such - anything that doesn't conflict.

Comment: What dimich said: _type_ plus something defines a new variable. In your case `int array[h]` creates a new int array, which will nearly immediately go out of scope, ie be lost, when the block ends on the closing curly bracket `}`. You want just `array[h] = 1` here, but note that the way your loop works, you will assign to `array[7]`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: It looks like you have other bugs as well.  For instance, where is `h` declared?

Comment: `h = 7` <-> `array[h]` doesn't go well assuming you fix according to @dimich ...

Comment: `h` is not declared/defined anywhere, your loop should look like `for(int h = ...`.

Comment: "_Also I had to rewrite all this code line by line copying..._" It's pointless trying to diagnose code that may-or-may-not be what the compiler is seeing... The OP should (eventually) figure out how to copy/paste the code into an SO question... _The devil's in the details..._

Comment: Besides array declaration and access out of its boundary, you are printing entire array on every iteration, when not all elements are filled. That's why you get "object may not be initialized". Move array printing out of `for (h=...` loop. However, you don't need an array at all to print binary digits of character code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a declaration of an array of type `int` (of size `7`)

```
int array[7];
```

this is the same declaration as above, but with initialization

```
int array[7] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Further code can access that array via the identifier `array`, like this

```
array[h] = 42;
```

but if you prefix the above expression with the keyword `int` (e.g. `int array[h] = {42};`), that is a new declaration of an array of type `int` (of size `h`). Since there already exists a variable with that name, the new declaration 'shadows' the previous one. Therefore the warning from the compiler (to make sure, that you know what you're doing).

Comment: thanks staring at this for hours not putting int array redeclaring and just saying array it works .very new to programing

Comment: @user21169834 If this has solved your (immediate) problem, check the check on the side to mark it so for bookkeeping. And welcome to SO!